# iText 7 Get font line height

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

I am trying to get the total line height (ascent + descent) of a font in iText 7 with page and font size given. I found methods like PdfFont.getAscent(String, float) but this one seems to return the ascent for that particular given string. I want to get the general ("maximum") size properties for a given font and font size, as is for example possible in Java AWT (FontMetrics.getHeight()). Is there a way to do this? Or is there some specific reason why there is no way, that I should know about?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is solved here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71289581/17931838

In a simple way, you need to extract the text from the pdf, and use itext tools to find the font height

Comment: Thanks for the reply already! The issue you linked talks about getting the font size in a loaded document when analyzing a particular paragraph right? I am generating a PDF though; so I don't have any data in advance.
Does that mean that I really have to generate a dummy PDF in advance just to be able to listen to this event and determine the constant line height that I should actually be able to deduce just with the context, font and font size given? :(